# what is the dif between requestMapping on controller and method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mapping

If I have:

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class RegistrationController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getRegisterPage(Model model) {
```

What is the difference? I mean what will happen if I remove the `/user` mapping, will my `/register` mapping still work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A @RequestMapping on the class level is not required. **Without it**, all paths are simply absolute, and not relative.

see [15.3.2 Mapping requests with @RequestMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

This means if you specify the classlevel annotations, the url shall be relative, so for register it shall be /user/register(URL to Handler mapping) and likewise.

Answer (score 3):

As described [here](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/java/spring/how-spring-controller-request-mapping-works-in-spring-mvc) you can also use Type level mapping and relative path mappings on method level to be dry and don't duplicate root at every methods.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee/*")
public class Employee {

    @RequestMapping("add")
    public ModelAndView add(
            @RequestParam(value = "firstName") String firstName,
            @RequestParam(value = "surName") String surName) {
        //....
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"remove","delete"})
    public ModelAndView delete(
        //....
    }   
}
```

> Spring doc: *At the method level, relative paths (e.g. "edit.do") are supported within the primary mapping expressed at the type level.*